# Does armor still apply double the penalty to Swim in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I can't find anywhere that you take double the penalty for swim checks when wearing full armor. Does it apply in Pathfinder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, armor penalty has been more streamlined, it is the same for every dex/str based skill:

> Any armor heavier than leather, as well as any shield, hurts a character's ability to use Dex- and Str-based skills. An armor check penalty applies to all Dex- and Strength-based skill checks. A character's encumbrance may also incur an armor check penalty.

Nothing different for Swim checks (more info [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2iq9s?Swim-armor-penalty-has-been-reduced-in)).